# CtCi 2.6: Implement a function to check if a linked list is a palindrome

Tags: c++, linked-list, interview-questions

I would appreciate feedback on the linked list implementation and usage below for question 2.6 from *Cracking the coding interview* book.

```
struct Node {
    char value;
    shared_ptr<Node> next;
    Node(char v) : value(v) {};
};

shared_ptr<Node> head;

void createSampleList(string str)
{
    auto ptr = head;
    for (const char ch : str)
    {
        if(!head) {
            head = make_shared<Node>(ch);
            ptr = head;
        }
        else {
            ptr->next = make_shared<Node>(ch);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}

bool isPalindrome() {

    auto slow = head;
    auto fast = head;
    stack<char> tempStack;

    while (fast != nullptr && fast->next != nullptr)
    {
        tempStack.push(slow->value);
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
    }

    if(fast != nullptr)
        slow = slow->next;

    while (slow != nullptr)
    {
       char reverseVal = tempStack.top();
        tempStack.pop();
        if(reverseVal != slow->value)
            return false;
        slow = slow->next;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would *not* use `char`, unless you have a *very* good reason. `int` should be the numeric type you use by default, since it's the default for both your system and the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `using namespace std;`. See any other C++ question for the reasons.

The declaration `createSampleList(string str)` means that when you pass a string to that function, the whole string will be copied. That's unnecessary. Declaring the function as `createSampleList(const string &str)` is much more efficient.

The variable name `tempStack` can be improved. The word `temp` should not appear here at all, since it doesn't *explain* anything about the code.

I was first confused on why you called `tempStack.pop()` two times in a row. But then I saw that it was `top` and `pop`. There's nothing you can do against that, since the C++ API just doesn't provide the method that combines these two. Maybe you could move the `tempStack.pop()` below the `if` sentence.

The `char reverseVal` line is not indented properly. Let your IDE fix the indentation.

After each `if`, there should be a space. Only for function calls the space should be omitted.

A general rule is that you should not use global variables. The global variable in this case is `head`. It is better to pass such variables as parameters. This corresponds to natural language speaking, where you would ask *Is the word `asdfdsa` a palindrome?* instead of *Is the word written at the wall over there a palindrome?*. This makes your code much more flexible.

The rest of the code looks great for learning algorithms. If you want to use that code in practice, it should be much shorter. Something like this:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrome(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string rev(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
    return str == rev;
}

int main()
{
    assert(is_palindrome(""));
    assert(is_palindrome("a"));
    assert(is_palindrome("aa"));
    assert(!is_palindrome("ab"));
    assert(!is_palindrome("aaabcaaa"));
}
```